# median split procedure reference

Tags: references, median, binning

Is there any reference that I might use when I mention the median split method in a paper? i.e. turning a continuous variable into a categorical one by splitting a sample into 2 (above and below the median).

Comment: Are you after a reference explaining how it's usually a really bad idea? I think I can dig up several of those. (If you're after a reference that says it's a good idea, I don't actually know of any.)

Comment: No actually I am using it...but to stratify my data for a first check...

Comment: For example I stratify according to the age (2 groups: above and below the median).

Comment: So you want a reference that advocates using it as some kind of first check? Or just at all?

Comment: [This answer by Jeromy Anglim](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10204/how-to-split-a-numeric-variable-into-a-binary-low-high-variable/10221#10221) contains links, some of which have references, a few of which might be of some use to you, since they discuss dichotomizing. There's also links in the answers [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43608/which-test-to-use-for-a-set-of-data/) that you may be able to find something in. [There are very few situations where it makes sense to do this, even for a first check -- it's no harder to run a regression than a t-test]

Comment: If you must split, there's some sensible advice in Gelman & Park (2008) "Splitting a Predictor at the Upper Quarter or Third
and the Lower Quarter or Third" The American Statistician, (Nov.), **62**:4 pp1-8 ([Gelman's link here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/thirds5.pdf)). Very similar advice can be found in a number of older works